# mo.js animation for multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help.
To apply animation to multiple elements with a single class of "my-button"? Now this only works for a single button.

Replacement **querySelector** on **querySelectorAll** not solve the problem, the script becomes not working

Thank you.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.my-button'),
 elSpan = el.querySelector('span'),
 // mo.js timeline obj
 timeline = new mojs.Timeline(),
 scaleCurve = mojs.easing.path('M0,100 L25,99.9999983 C26.2328835,75.0708847 19.7847843,0 100,0'),

 // tweens for the animation:

 // burst animation
 tween1 = new mojs.Burst({
  parent: el,
  duration: 1500,
  shape : 'circle',
  fill : [ '#e67e22', '#DE8AA0', '#8AAEDE', '#8ADEAD', '#DEC58A', '#8AD1DE' ],
  x: '50%',
  y: '50%',
  opacity: 0.8,
  childOptions: { radius: {20:0} },
  radius: {40:120},
  angle: {0: 180},
  count: 8,
  isSwirl: true,
  isRunLess: true,
  easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1)
 }),
 // ring animation
 tween2 = new mojs.Transit({
  parent: el,
  duration: 750,
  type: 'circle',
  radius: {0: 50},
  fill: 'transparent',
  stroke: '#2ecc71',
  strokeWidth: {15:0},
  opacity: 0.6,
  x: '50%',     
  y: '50%',
  isRunLess: true,
  easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1)
 }),
 // icon scale animation
 tween3 = new mojs.Tween({
  duration : 900,
  onUpdate: function(progress) {
   if(progress > 0.3) {
    var scaleProgress = scaleCurve(progress);
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(' + scaleProgress + ',' + scaleProgress + ',1)';
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = '#2ecc71';
   } else {
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(0,0,1)';
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
   }
  }
 });

// add tweens to timeline:
timeline.add(tween1, tween2, tween3);

// when clicking the button start the timeline/animation:
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
 timeline.start();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 height: 200px;
}

.my-button {
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
}
svg {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.send-icon {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netgon.net/mo.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <button class="my-button">
  <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
 </button>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ey_intuitive/pen/NxQdyY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [Working CodePen Here!](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/KNEyaZ)

the "parent element" **el** must be a single element, so achieving this would be tricky and create a complicated messy code.

so I created a different method that'll create the animations once and set their position using **tune()** when a button is clicked, this will improve performance since you only have one animation object in the DOM.

instead of creating three animations for each parent/button.
I listen to the all buttons with the class "my-button" set animation's top and left values accordingly

```
$( ".my-button" ).on( "click", function() {
  aniPos = findCenter($(this));
  myAnimation1.tune({ top: aniPos.y, left: aniPos.x });
  myAnimation2.tune({ top: aniPos.y, left: aniPos.x });
  myTimeline.replay();
```

anipos is calculated with a simple function that'll return an object with .x and .y values

```
function findCenter ($this) {
  var offset = $this.offset();
  var width = $this.width();
  var height = $this.height();
   IDs = {
    x: offset.left + (width / 2),
    y: offset.top + (height / 2)
  };
  console.log(offset);
  return IDs;
}
```

I also added a method to animate the clicked button automatically.

```
 elSpan = this.querySelector('span');
 new mojs.Tween({
    duration : 900,
    onUpdate: function(progress) {
        if(progress > 0.3) {
            var scaleProgress = scaleCurve(progress);
            elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(' + scaleProgress + ',' + scaleProgress + ',1)';
            elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = '#2ecc71';
        } else {
            elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(0,0,1)';
            elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
        }
    }
}).play();
```

});

please note that my example will require JQuery to work.

I used the exact animations you provided but you can change them as long as you don't change **X**, **Y**, **top** and **left** properties